# Loop for adding collection members

Tags: excel, vba, m-files-api

I am not the most advanced professor when it comes into loops so I am a little bit stuck here.

Normally I would use it like:

```
    Dim ouLookup: Set ouLookup = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.Lookup")
    Dim ouLookups: Set ouLookups = CreateObject("MFilesAPI.Lookups")

    ouLookup.Item = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value
    ouLookup.Version = -1
    ouLookups.Add -1, ouLookup

    ouLookup.Item = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value
    ouLookup.Version = -1
    ouLookups.Add -1, ouLookup

    etc.
```

By this code we are adding user ID's to our collection `ouLookups` that we will use later in this code:

```
' AssignedToUsers
oPropertyValue.PropertyDef = MFBuiltInPropertyDefAssignedTo
oPropertyValue.Value.SetValueToMultiSelectLookup ouLookups ' It is here
oPropertyValues.Add -1, oPropertyValue
```

Is it possible to built a loop code for adding user ID's? So it will do this operation in a loop from cell `E1` to `E35`:

```
    ouLookup.Item = ThisWorkbook... ' Offset or something?
    ouLookup.Version = -1
    ouLookups.Add -1, ouLookup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops are very easy, there's loads of tutorial available online. Definitely look into it :)

Here's how you can use a loop in your case

```
'set range
Set myrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E35")

'loop through each cell in range
For Each cel In myrng
    'this is how you cna access the value
    MsgBox cel.Value
Next
```